# Change WooCommerce product column CSS for Shop page only

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am using the latest Wordpress with the Storefront Theme & Child Theme.

I am wanting to change the `height:` and `padding:` of the columns for WooCommerce's products (actually categories but they use the same columns).
On the shop page **only** the categories are displayed which do not require to be as tall as product columns (no price, no sale tag, no buy now or add to cart button etc are on categories)

I am using this small piece of PHP in my Child Theme Functions to try and implement this but it doesn't seem to change anything, nor are any errors given:

```
function dayles_custom_shop_columns()
{
    if (function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop()) {
        echo "<style type='text/css'>.storefront-full-width-content .site-main ul.products.columns-4 li.product, ul.products li.product {height:320px!important;padding:20px!important;min-height:320px!important;max-height:320px!important;}</style>";
    } else {
       //Do nothing.
    }
}
```

I have also tried this using !important to see if it had any difference. But nope.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where do you use this code? Is it inside action hook?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, I have updated the code in the question to show the full function to which I am using in my Child Theme Functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a wp_head action hook in your functions:

Example:

```
function my_custom_css() {
     if (function_exists('is_shop') && is_shop()) {
        echo "<style type='text/css'>.storefront-full-width-content .site-main ul.products.columns-4 li.product, ul.products li.product {height:320px!important;padding:20px!important;min-height:320px!important;max-height:320px!important;}</style>";
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_css' );
```

More information on wp_head action [`here`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

Comment: Ahh yes of course! -  *Slaps forehead!*
 Thanks for point this out. I missed my add_action.

Comment: Coming back to this, it works perfectly, but I also noticed that if people use the search box on the page this also effects the columns. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Try to remove this from added CSS: `ul.products li.product`

Answer (score 0):

To make the product loop on shop page of same height, please wrap all the loop items in your custom div and then write your style.

Paste the below code in current active theme **functions.php** file

```
function start_before_shop_loop_item() {
   echo '<div class="custom_shop_loop_wrap">';
}
function end_after_shop_loop_item() {
  echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'start_before_shop_loop_item', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'end_after_shop_loop_item', 10 );
```

Then using the class `custom_shop_loop_wrap` add your styling.

```
function custom_css_add_wrap(){?>
<style>
    .custom_shop_loop_wrap{
      height:height:320px;
      max-height:320px;
}
</style>
   <?php }
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_css_add_wrap' );
```